# Не можем публиковать проект в LG Store из за иконки

Tags: javascript, веб-дизайн, дизайн, photoshop, samsung

уважаемые разработчики, дизайнеры.
Не давно разрабатывали проект на ОС WebOS для LG телевизоров.
Проект разработан на чистый JS, наши дизайнеры подготовили иконки для приложения по требованиям которое указано в 
http://webostv.developer.lge.com/design/style/icon/
3 - раз уже пытаемся пройти верификацию для публикации проекта, 3 раз игнорируют по причине того что:
https://gyazo.com/10339eb0a39755fa08a4a4805cd9cd5c

Хотя все иконки сделаны по их требованиям.
Кто нибудь сталкивался подобным вопросом? И кто нибудь опубликовал проект в LG Store? Поделитесь опытом пож.

Comment: Ссылка на иконки:

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1CYzg16LOj6o2w315i_cO0JncJVIsXnwk

Answer (score 1):

У вашей иконки нет заднего фона (то есть прозрачный фон) или он не однотонный. Сделайте заливку заднего фона и все примут

Comment: Покажите иконку, и я постараюсь вам помочь

Comment: Да конечно, спасибо. Дело в том, что иконка она background - ом только solid идет, но все равно они не принимают. Ссылка на иконки ниже:

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1CYzg16LOj6o2w315i_cO0JncJVIsXnwk